# Android timer one thread only

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

I'm having problem with Android timer's scheduleAtFixedRate option.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask myTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
};
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, 0, 5000);
```

This snippet is doing bad things for me. It's executed in the service so every time method is called timer creates a new thread and executes the same code while the old thread is still running; that creates performance problems. I need to run the code in the run() method every 5 seconds but I want the old task to be canceled. Is there any way to handle this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `timer.cancel()` to stop the timer.

For example, I had an end button to finish the timer early:

```
finishEarlyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View arg0) {

              timer.cancel();

          }
    });
```